# How to multi-sort with strings and multiple types in MongoDB (JS)?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, nosql

How would I sort by **str !null && exists** >> **bool is true** >> **createDate is from newest** to oldest, in that order?

Here is what I tried:

```
// -1 = descending/newest, right?
var sort = 
{
    "str" : -1, // str will either null, "" or "filled". I don't think this works.
    "bool" : -1,  // bool will be true or false. Seems to maybe work.
    "createDate" : -1 // date obj. Seems to work.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that **bool** works, **createDate** works, but **str** did not work:

I found that bool and createDate filtered fine -- it was just the string did not. I made a script to go through all my db to add a bool if str existed (and added to script for future use).

Thus:

```
// -1 = descending/newest
var sort = 
{
    "strExistsBool" : -1,
    "bool" : -1,
    "createDate" : -1
};
```

Then used:

```
db.collection.find(someQuery).sort(sort)
```

Answer (score -1):

The first two conditions in your question are actually to filter records and the third one sorts the resultset. Try this query.

```
db.collection.find({'str':{$ne:null,$exists:true},'bool':true}).sort({'createDate' : -1})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure you understand the question: In OP, I put `var sort` to imply that it's a sort object of it's own. I am trying to multi-sort, not filter. Filter by A, then B, then C.